# access to iframe contents of local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the file `file:///C:/index.html` that has an iframe inside it:

```
<iframe id="folder_browser" src="file:///C:/Files/"></iframe>
```

the contents of the `Files` folder load into the iframe but I can not access to them by javascript or jquery. what can I do?

I have tried `$('#folder_browser').contents().find('body').html();` but no luck!

Comment: you can't do anything due to the same origin policy. Use a webserver.

Comment: you can drag into the other pane, use an <input type=file> to browse, write a batch file that outputs a json folder listing to consume in your main page, or use a more advanced deployment setup like HTA, Chrome Packaged Apps, "node-webkit" (one word), WinJS/win8, or adobe AIR.

Comment: I just want to get list of files in the folder!

Comment: If browsers could go grabbing file listings, we'd be in big trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Cause "Same origin policy" you can't get the content of an iframe either in this kind of situations nor in the case you have the main page from a domain and the iframe document from another domain.

"Same origin policy" is a set of restrictions that browsers apply to webpages to prevent communicating each other. These restrictions prevent a lot of security issues from internet web sites like accessing to your private data stored on your local machine using tricks like that one.

Nevertheless there are some ways (and conditions) to bypass these restrictions:

1. window.document.domain variable manipulation
2. Proxy
3. Cross Document Messaging

But this is possible only if both pages are into the same domain and by modifying the content of both html pages (in particular their javascripts) so pages can authorize each other communications. This can be only done if both the parent page and the iframe child page are web pages: in this case the address **file:///C:/something/** is not a web address, it is a local directory.

It is possible to find some interesting tutorials about same origin policy
at

[Bypass Same Origin Policy](http://qnimate.com/same-origin-policy-in-nutshell/)
,

and

[Same-origin policy for file: URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs)
.

In this last one in particular you can read "The new **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** preference, which defaults to true, can be set to false if the user doesn't want to strictly enforce the same origin policy on file: URIs."

Another interesting information resource is:

[Bypassing the Same-Origin-Policy For Local Files During Development](https://juplo.de/bypassing-the-same-origin-policiy-for-loal-files-during-development/)
.

In which I found the following hint that may help:

> The only real cross-browser solution to circumvent the problem altogether is to serve the content with a local webserver, so that you can access it through HTTP.

In other words you have to install a web server software into your computer and configure it to serve files under an address like http:///yourlocalwebserverdirectory.

Nevertheless you can get files (with the interaction of the user) by using the html input type file, here a working example:

```js
document.getElementById('loadfile').onchange = function(event) {
  var files = loadfile.files;
  var len = files.length;
  var outpt = document.getElementById('filelist');
  
   for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
     {
       outpt.innerHTML += files[i].name + '<br>';
     }
 }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="loadfile" name="files[]" multiple = "multiple" title="load one or more files" autofocus="autofocus" />

<div id="filelist"></div>
```

Comment: What I find wired is that browsers don't recognize as same origin (so do not authorize to work together) two files I put into the same directory on a local drive. In fact is out of my comprehension why two files that are both into *mydrive/mypath/* and are called main.html and insideiframe.html are an issue for browsers if they access, comunicate or get data or content from each other. I do understand the issue if they were one in adomain.com and the other in anotherdomain.com but in my own local drive and even into the same local directory... that's seems more like an overkill