# iframe returning null valuew

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store a table data in an html file and access the table data from another HTML file for which I am doing the following

```
<iframe id ="mytabledata" src="data.html" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

```js
var thisvar = document.getElementById("mytabledata").contentWindow;
var gt=thisvar.document.getElementById("demovar");
```

I have a `p` tag `demovar` in the data.html file but it is returning `NULL` value and I cant access the file data.html.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access to iframe contents of local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362008/access-to-iframe-contents-of-local-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its working.

```
 <iframe width="500" height="300" src="./data.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

js:

```
  var row = document.getElementById("mytabledata");
  var content= (row.contentWindow || row.contentDocument);
  if (content.document)content = content.document;
  var cell = row.querySelector("#demovar");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I am getting the Uncaught error thisvar.querySelector is not a function

Comment: Try the above condition.